# PHP proc_open() pipes communication

Tags: php, shell

The context is the following:

- I'm using a Raspberry Pi with `PHP5` and `Apache` installed on it and it's connected to a LED display.
- There are a few executables on the Pi to make this LED display works.
- I want my php script to fetch datas from the web with some APIs and display the result on the LED.

So, the display works fine. I have installed a C-based program in the the /var/www/ and here is an example

on `/var/www/`: `sudo ./text-example -f fonts/5x8.bdf -r 16`

(-f for the font used, -r for the number of rows of my LED)

When you execute this, you can write some text in the shell and it will display it on the LED.

So I made a simple `test.php` script with the following: `$res = shell_exec('sudo ./test-example -f fonts/5x8.bdf -r 16');` and it works too. I can enter messages in the `STDIN`.

A little further, now I need to enter the text dynamically so I did a `proc_open()` in a `proc.php`:

```
<?php
$desc = array(0=>array("pipe", "r"), 1=>array("pipe", "w"));
$cwd = '/var/www/';
$process = proc_open('php test.php', $desc, $pipes, $cwd, NULL);

if (is_resource($process)) {
   fwrite($pipes[0], 'hello');
   fclose($pipes[0]);

}
?>
```

So, now I run in the shell: `php proc.php`. As soon as I define a `$desc` with pipe, the programm will execute, and then stop. The LED display is not displaying anything. If I remove the `$desc` variable and remove the pipes things (`fwrite`, `fclose`), I can enter text in the shell and it will execute properly as if it was `test.php`. I don't understand why it won't let me `STDIN` with `fwrite` and why the php is interrupted with theses pipes.

Comment: Try changing the first descriptor to: `1 => array("file", "php://stdout")` - this will allow the child process to directly write to your stdout. Otherwise you could read the stdout of the child-process after the `fclose($pipes[0]);` - for example with `echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); fclose($pipes[1]);` - in that case you can leave your $desc-array as it is now.

Comment: As I understood, it's the process point of view, so I need `php://stdin` and not `php://stdout` right ?

Comment: stdout should be correct, since the goal is to pipe the stdout of the child process "somewhere" (to prevent blocking, which I assume is what happens). If you pipe the child's stdout to the parent's stdin it might prevent blocking (since the write operation on a "read-only" file handle probably fails) but it's technically not correct.

Comment: So, I did a lot of testing and it seems that it's not working only when the `0 => array("pipe", "r")` is on. Any idea ?

Comment: Hmm well the first thing I would do is add a `proc_close` at the end of the `if (is_resource($process))`-block. Otherwise PHP does not wait for the child process to finish (maybe that causes a hickup - in my tests it did not change anything but I couldn't exactly reproduce the problem here). If that does not work then I would use `strace -f ...` to see what is happening at syscall-level - maybe that can give you (or us if you add the output to your question) an insight where the problem is.